# Cryptographic exception in X509Certificate2 constructor

Tags: c#, cryptography, x509certificate, sha256, x509certificate2

I am getting the following exception when trying to convert pkcs12 string in bytes to X509Certificate2 type using the constructor.

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: An internal error
>   occurred.    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr)

The strange thing is, it works perfectly fine for SHA-1 certificate but fails for SHA-2 certificate.

I Tried setting load user Profile to true and setting the following flags in constructor but no success.

```
X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet|
 X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet|
 X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable
```

Any help in this regard is much appreciated. the IIS server is W-2008.

Comment: Please, provide relevant code parts where it fails.